# React-native: Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE?

Tags: react-native

I kept getting the error `Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE?`. I've walked my environment all the way back to doing a fresh install (per below) and I still get the error.

```
$ react-native init test
$ cd coms
$ react-native run-ios
```

Generates the error above. For reference:

```
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.48.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tossing this up on stackoverflow - maybe it will help someone.  The React Packager was running minimized out of mind, and was in a state that began generating errors forward in Xcode, terminal and simulator. Killed the packager and everything began working as expected.

Comment: Just got this tonight after Xcode had to install something new. Can you elaborate on your fix?  What does "minimized out of mind" mean?  What packager are you talking about?

Comment: By "minimized out of mind", I mean I literally minimized the terminal window that packager was running in and later forgot it was even running. Changes in my code or environment would not translate forward into my application, because the packager sits in the middle.  The packager is launched automatically as part of the standard react build process (and stays running for subsequent builds).